# Can anyone provide any translation of this tombstone?

Tags: german-to-english, blackletter

[image]
This is an old family headstone.  I realize the lettering is hard to make out, Any help with translation would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi Stephanie! If you deem the answer helpful, please upvote (by clicking the up arrow icon on it) and accept it (by checking the check mark on it). This is the way we acknowledge the effort of others and distribute gratitude on this website. It builds up the reputation of the authors and it makes it easy for future readers to assess the value of the answer.

Answer (score 23):

> wir haben euch zur Ruh gebracht
> ihr schlaft nun eine lange Nacht
> kein Ruf zu wecken euch vermag
> als die Posaun am jüngsten Tag

In English it is something along the lines

> we have brought you to rest
> you will now sleep a long night
> no call can awaken you
> except for the trombone on Judgment Day

Comment: Instead of trombone, English bible translations prefer trumpet.The instrument the bible texts refer to is probably quite different from a modern trombone or trumpet.

Comment: @RHa Ha, right. In English at least "trumpet" is almost as all-purpose as "horn" for a loud blaring sound or the instrument that produces one, whereas "trombone" could only refer to the spirally brass thingamabob.